# Pandas DataFrame efficient moving of data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a huge csv like this that I need to change to the format below.
I tried do do it with a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import StringIO, pandas as pd

data='''Team,Date,Metric,Value,Unit
A,2011,Speed,10,km/h
A,2011,Weight,3,kg
B,2011,Speed,20,km/h
B,2011,Weight,6,kg
'''
d = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data))
```

I need to get the data in the format:

```
Team,  Date,  Speed (km/h), Weight (kg)
A,     2011,  10,           3
B,     2011,  20,           6
```

This is just an exemple, in reality my files are big, there are 100 metric and millions of lines and I need to do it efficiently. I tried with groupby, but I still need to combine the units with the Metric and to transpose the value.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reshape the data, take a look at pandas `pivot_table` function ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html)).

```
In [458]: d = d.pivot_table(index=['Team','Date'], columns=['Metric', 'Unit']).reset_index()
```

Then, I made a little function to rename the columns.  The pivot table will have a MultiIndex as the columns, this collapses it down to combined the name/units.

```
In [456]: def column_builder(col_tuple):
     ...:     if col_tuple[0] == 'Value':
     ...:         return ' '.join(col_tuple[1:])
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return col_tuple[0]

In [460]: d.columns = [column_builder(c) for c in d.columns]

In [461]: d
Out[461]: 
  Team  Date  Speed km/h  Weight kg
0    A  2011          10          3
1    B  2011          20          6
```

Comment: Awesome, it's perfect and fast !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this :

```
df1 = data[data['Metric'] == 'Speed']
df2 = data[data['Metric'] == 'Weight']

del df1['Unit']
del df2['Unit']
del df1['Metric']
del df2['Metric']

df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Value':'Speed (km/h)'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'Value':'Weight (kg)'})

new_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = ['Team','Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a groupby and merge here:

```
In [11]: def extract_speed_with_unit(sub_df):
             row = sub_df.iloc[0]
             col_name = '%s (%s)' % (row['Metric'], row['Unit'])
             clean_sub_df = sub_df[['Team', 'Date']]  # makes a copy here
             clean_sub_df[col_name] = sub_df['Value']
             return clean_sub_df
```

This function just takes the view of the sub dataframe (for each group) and pull out the Team and Date columns and adds in the Metric + Unit column:

```
In [12]: g = d.groupy('Metric')

In [13]: pd.merge(*(extract_speed_with_unit(v) for k, v in g))
Out[13]:
  Team  Date  Speed (km/h)  Weight (kg)
0    A  2011            10            3
1    B  2011            20            6
```